# Android : savedInstanceState null when launching application

Tags: android, onsaveinstancestate

Android : I always have `savedInstanceState == null` when I relaunch my app.
I have a fragment where I want to store / reuse data after stopping the application.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mPrefs = android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mLoading = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(OUTSTATE_LOADING, false);
        mCurrentFiliere = savedInstanceState.getInt(OUTSTATE_CURRENT_FILIERE, 0);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(OUTSTATE_CURRENT_FILIERE, mCurrentFiliere);
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentFiliere = savedInstanceState.getInt(OUTSTATE_CURRENT_FILIERE);
    }
}
```

Both methods `onCreate` and `onViewStateRestored` return `null`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And I haven't found any answer in other posts...

Comment: It is normal that the value is null at launch. You finished the application yourself and then it is null. Its different when your application is killed by the OS for instance when you start a camera app. Then you can use onSaveInstanceState to save some variable values and get them back in savedInstanceState when the OS recreates your app automatically.

Comment: @blackapps Ok, and what would be the correct way to save data between 2 launchs of the app ?

Comment: In shared preferences or in a file or in a database.

Comment: @blackapps So savedInstanceState it's only between onCreate and onStop. And preferences it's onDestroy.

Comment: Dont know. What i know is that it is only not null when the OS recreates your Activity. Not when you kill your activity yourself.

Comment: Please dont delete. It was a normal question. Nothing strange. And there are not many questions about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, due to a lack of comprehension of me of the saves on Android, my question isn't very good because my code works fine!
Indeed if I don't close my application, I don't lose any data.
My issue was how to conserve data when I close my application and the answer is to use `preferences`. And this way i can close my application and relaunch it without losing the saved data.
It's obvious when we know the correct way to save....
My mistake was (very simply): savedInstanceState save between `onCreate` and `onStop` and `preferences` save when you are on `onDestroy`

Answer (score 0):

You may know about [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) , to avoid loose data between Instance Sate while orientation change , pickup phone call etc, use `SaveInstanceState`. Otherwise use `shared preferences`.

Save-

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.putString("testkey", "testvalue");
                        editor.commit();
```

To get-

```
SharedPreferences defPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String restore  = defPref.getString("testkey","");
```

Example class-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button add;
private TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textviewYear);

    SharedPreferences defPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String restore  = defPref.getString("testkey","");
    textView.setText(restore);



    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString("testkey", "testvalue");
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
}
 }
```